# Why length should be subtype of the indexer?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

I see an example in the TypeScript handbook at [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-function-types).
I don't understand why the `length` property is not valid?

```
interface Dictionary {
  [index: string]: string;
  length: number;    // error, the type of 'length' is not a subtype of the indexer
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `x['length']` is a number, but you said that indexing `x` string produces a string. They can't both be true.

Comment: So is it like JavaScript that properties are accessible in a dictionary like way!?

Comment: TypeScript is a syntactic superset of JavaScript.